# Vue bind multiple class with conditional

Tags: vue.js

I have the following div in my component:

```
<div :class="sidebarOpen ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out transition-medium' : '-translate-x-full ease-in transition-medium'" class="sidebar fixed z-30 inset-y-0 left-0 w-64 px-8 py-4 border-r overflow-auto lg:static lg:inset-auto lg:translate-x-0">
```

I want to add another class to this, which is a computed property:

```
computed: {
    borderColor() {
        return {
            "bg-white": this.$apollo.loading,
            [colorBorder[this.board?.color]]: true
        }
    },
}
```

Can anyone advise how I can do this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the array syntax :

```html
<div :class="[sidebarOpen ?'...':'...',borderColor]"
```